# Why instance initializers require *final* for outer variables in Java?

Tags: java, parameters, anonymous-class

What semantics would the second example violate if it had access to the outer variable?

```
class A {
    void f() {
        int outer = 1;

        // Access non-final outer variable through helper method
        new A() {
            int inner;
            void init(int inner) {
                this.inner = inner;
            }
        }.init(outer); // OK

        // Access non-final outer variable through instance initializer
        new A() {
            {
                // int inner = outer; // Does not compile
            }
        };

        outer = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The second one has no semantics at all, as it does not compile.

Comment: Hasn't this requirement been dropped from Java 8 ?

Comment: @vikingsteve in Java 8 you can pass the outer variable if it's effectively final.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? This compiles for me in Java 8 when I uncomment your "does not compile" line.

Comment: @swingMan I use Java 7. It compiles in Java 8 because `outer` keeps its value therefore it's effectively final.

Comment: @swingMan I fixed that issue. Now it does not compile in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with *instance initializers*, but rather with the fact that you are *capturing* an outer local variable. If you *captured* the outer local variable in your helper method, it would equally not work:

```
new A() {
    int inner;
    void init() {
        this.inner = outer;
    }
}.init();
```

When you *capture* an outer local variable in a local or anonymous class, that outer local variable must be `final` (in Java 7 or before) or *effectively `final`* (in Java 8+). Your variable `outer` is not `final`, and (after your most recent edit) is not *effectively `final`* (which means it would still compile if it were declared as `final`), because you assign to it later.

Captured local variables are required to be `final` or effectively `final` due to the way Java implements capturing. In Java, when an object of a local or anonymous class is created, any local variables it captures are assigned (as if by `=`) into a separate independent copy inside the object (because the object may outlive the local scope where it was created). The variable state is not "shared" between the original local scope and the object(s) that capture it, even though they have the same name and only one variable was declared. Therefore, if you could assign to the variable, changes to one copy of the variable would not be reflected in the other copies, and it would be inconsistent. To prevent this, they prevent you from assigning to any version of the variable, by requiring that it be effectively `final`.

Comment: I understand all these, but isn't the instance initializer effectively a constructor? The `inner` gets the outer value and it's done. The `outer` can get a different value later, why does it matter? Perhaps the limitation is there to keep the implementation simple because we can create anonymous classes inside initializers as well.

Comment: @NickDandoulakis: Yes, and if you had a constructor that *captured* (as opposed to being passed) an outer local variable, the same thing would happen. When you *capture* a variable, you never "declared" a new variable anywhere, so the programmer expects it to be the "same variable", and so should be consistent with other places that use that variable. When you *pass* a value as a parameter, that is very different, as it's declared to be a new variable (the parameter).

Comment: @NickDandoulakis: "The outer can get a different value later, why does it matter?" Well, `outer` might not just be used in the inner class in the initialization. It could also be used in some other method that is called later. So if `outer` is changed in another context it would matter. Or conversely something in the inner class could change `outer` and it would not be visible in the original context. For consistency the same rule is applied for all capturing. If you intend that the inner class gets a separate copy, then you can assign `outer` to `outer2` and then capture that.

Comment: When we use an outer variable we *capture* it, fine. But when we only assign it to an inner variable during initialization that's different. I was asking about the latter because Java could detect that the outer isn't used elsewhere.